# Why is my Heroku application not recognizing the created cookies in my browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Cookies are not being recognized by the application on the Heroku server. I see the available cookie for the myapp.herokuapp.com website in Chrome and Firefox, but the application doesn't see it. This works fine in my local environment running the "thin" web server and the application sees the cookie.

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks!

sessions_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    user = User.where(:email => params[:session][:email]).first
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

sessions_helper.rb:

```
  def log_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:token] = user.token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.where(:token => cookies[:token]).first
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end
```

Comment: Where's the code that reads the cookie?

Comment: Added the current_user method code that reads the cookie.